# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[***]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[***]'

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have an object `DirectoryToken` that inherits from the class `Token`. In my code I have a `GetValues` method which takes a list of tokens, and puts together the value for each item in the list based on the information contained in the token object.

```
//NameTokens is an object of type **List<DirectoryToken>**
List<String> PathValues = GetValues((IEnumerable<Token>)settings.DirectoryDefinition.**NameTokens**.OrderBy(x => x.Index));


private List<String> GetReportValues(IEnumerable<Token> TokenList)
{

}
```

What I notice is when I run the code on one machine (Windows 7, .NET 3.5), it runs fine. However, when I move the built msi to another machine and try to run the same test, I get the following error message.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[DirectoryToken,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Token]'.

I don't think changing the code is the right way to attack this issue. Any suggestions what this problem could be from and maybe what version I can update my 3.5 to, to remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert a collection of `DirectoryToken` to a collection of `Token`.

This is called a *covariant* conversion, and it's only supported in .Net 4.0 or later.

If you can't upgrade, you can call `.Cast<Token>()` to create a new `IEnumerable<T>` instance (actually an iterator) that casts each object to the desired type.

Under no circumstances do you need an explicit cast operation.

Answer (score 2):

Right, not quite there yet.

```
List<String> PathValues = GetValues(settings.DirectoryDefinition.NameTokens.OrderBy(x => x.Index).Cast<Token>());
```

will work.

This is because although `DirectoryToken` is a `Token`, `IEnumerable<DirectoryToken>` is **NOT** an `IEnumerable<Token>`. You can't just cast directly do that.